# Determine if a dtypes Object should be an Int or float

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to determine what the majority of dtypes are for column entries. I'm in the process of automating a dataframe processing function that determines if an object class is full of `strings` or full of `int or float` but had unknown `strings` in it. I know that by typing the following, one can identify the datatype for the column but what about the entries.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.dtypes
```

output

```
Name       object
Age        object
dtype: object
```

What would be the best method for identifying if a column is being labelled incorrectly. example data is here

```
df.Age
Out[25]: 
0          25
1          23
2          24
3          26
4          30
5          18
6          22
7          19
8          23
9          20
10    Refused
11         23
12         29
Name: Age, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can seelct only object columns (obviously `strings`) by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), then try convert [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - it convert not parseble values to `NaN`s, so test if at least one non `NaN` by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
for c in df.select_dtypes(object).columns:
    if pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce').notna().any():
        print (c)
```